# Android app using Firebase slow on most old devices

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 2 apps already being used by my customers. Those apps uses Firebase as a DB.

Since those 2 customers and their crew started to input data, I've reached a point where it's becoming very slow, specially on old android devices.

I'm using this structure for one simple task that may be good for an example here:

under USERS i have all my users' IDs and under each ID I have this:

```
{
  "checkin" : {
    "Data: 1-11-2018 Horario checkin: 19:02" : {
      "ano" : "2018",
      "checkIn" : true,
      "checkoutCorrect" : true,
      "dia" : "1",
      "hora" : "19",
      "latitude" : "-22.42003992",
      "longitude" : "-45.4668167",
      "mes" : "11",
      "minuto" : "02",
      "nomePaciente" : "NAME 2"
    },
    (...)
  },
  "checkout" : {    
    (...)
  },
  "pacientes" : {
    "NAME" : "Mon Oct 01 20:16:36 GMT-11:00 2018"
  },
  "user type" : "FUNCIONARIO",
  "usuario" : {
    "alreadyAtribuidoAoPaciente" : false,
    "datanascimento" : "03/05/1970",
    "deviceModel" : "motorola XT1097",
    "funcao" : "TECNICO DE ENFERMAGEM",
    "lastLogin" : "7-3-2019 18:52",
    "nome" : "NAME",
    "nroconselho" : "530918",
    "telefone" : "35999428676",
    "tipousuario" : "FUNCIONARIO",
    "userID" : "8H1tHvz3BcR3XeCjz6BWXvC9fFM2",    
    "version" : "2.00"
  }
}
```

Important: "Checkin" and "Checkout" have a lot of information inside.

Now I want to check the list of users and I tap the button:

```
ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReferenceUsuarios().keepSynced(true); //this is the Firebase reference to USERS explained above
startActivity(intentThatHasAList);
```

after the new activity starts I load the data by doing:

```
valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (final DataSnapshot snap: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if (snap.child("user type").getValue().equals("ADMIN")){
                        final Usuario recordUser = new Usuario();
                        recordUser.setName(snap.child("usuario").child("nome").getValue().toString());
                        //...
                        recordUser.setId(snap.getKey());

                        listUsuarios.add(recordUser);
                    }
                    reorderArray();

                }

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        };

        ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReferenceUsuarios()
                .addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

seems like a simple code that wants to retrieve the information right?
However, this simple task is slow on devices with low memory so I guess by the fact that the database already got large amount of data, it may be retrieving data not only from those references.

First I thought that that "keepsynced" line of code (since it will sync all under it and there are lots of users each of them containing lots of CHECKIN and CHECKOUT) was the problem, but after I removed it, the app is still slow.

If anyone got good experience with Firebase this could be a helpful example and common issue for most people.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe not spell out latitude and longitude ie lat lon.  Its a few less bits to send/receive.  Makes a difference on old phones alreadyAtribuidoAoPaciente bRegistered.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

After Ive posted this question I had an insight.

By doing this:

```
 ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseReferenceUsuarios()
                .addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
```

I get ALL the information inside it, including each user and each CHECKIN and CHECKOUT for it... so i must use another path with less info. That was causing all the slowness.

Solutuion: move all the BASIC data to a new path where the CHECKIN and CHECKOUT (which has a huge data information) is not present.